# jquery validate() get current form in submitHandler

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a page with multiple forms to validate the code below works fine but I am having trouble when trying to access the $.validator object to get a reference of the validated form selector/id that is being stored as "currentForm"

```
    $("form.validate").each(function(){

         $(this).validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
               console.log($(this));
            }
         });

    });
```

The Console.log ==

```
[$.validator, init: function, selector: "", jquery: "1.4.2", size: function, toArray: function…]
0: $.validator
containers: c.fn.c.init[0]
currentElements: c.fn.c.init[12]
currentForm: form#thisForm1.validate
...
```

Why doesnt - $.validator.currentForm give me the value for currentForm?

I have tried validator.currentForm.id & validator.currentForm as well as many other combos. Any ideas on how I can get that value to use in my submitHandler to reference the subbed form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `form` argument passed to the `submitHandler` method, it refers to the submitted form element. See the documentation for [submitHandler](http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/)

```
$("form.validate").each(function(){

     $(this).validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
           console.log(form, $(form));
        }
     });

});
```

Comment: Thank you sir. $(form).attr('id') worked perfectly. I will accept when I can.